# What would stop apache2 for writing in error log

Tags: logging, apache-2.4

I usually test my under development website on my own machine, running apache2, and for debug, I type `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`, and it always did good, until a few days ago.

Most of the messages are simply not written inside this file anymore (and yes, I made coding error on purpose to be sure). I say "most of", because sometimes I get some messages. But I see no recurring pattern that would justify the fact they're here (I get Notices and Warnings from PHP)

For the record, I'm running Ubuntu 14.10, and `apache2 -v` responds with

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 17:25:11
```

and here's a [link to my apache2.conf](https://paste.aperture-sc.net/?9bd648f9f187e192#THkQUoyy8bD/vqsdU0uez9v/JnbyTwm%20YRl1FHOsMvo=)

Comment: Are you using piped logging to some program which would rotate that `error.log` file out from underneath your `tail` command?

Comment: Nope, no pipe of any kind, neither in my code, neither in my terminal aliases or environment.